# Can not connect to MongoDB by using Shanty

Tags: php, mongodb

I cant connect to MongoDb through by using MongoDB.
The first problem is while i tried to connect through an interface of Shanty_Mongo_Connection, system return error like:
***'Cant not found class Mongo in ".../Shanty/Mongo/Connection.php" on line 15'***. 
After that, I take a look at Mongo.php file and I discover that the class was defined in this file is Shanty_Mongo except Mongo, and then I make some change on the Connection.php file like this:

From:

> class Shanty_Mongo_Connection extends Mongo

To:

> class Shanty_Mongo_Connection extends Shanty_Mongo

And it worked for me, but the next difficulty is some wrong on the construct function. And the error looks like:
***'Can not call constructor on ".../Shanty/Mongo/Connection.php" on line 35'***

On this line, the class call 'construct' function of it's parent ( Shanty_Mongo ), but there are no 'construct' class in Shanty_Mongo class. And i don't know how to get over this trouble.

Can someone help me plz. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, the problem is Mongo extension, I have to install it to ph